# get selected value from datalist on change

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, datalist, html-datalist

I'm using a datalist (from Bootstrap) that is populated with a database call. When the user selects one of the items from the datalist, I want to determine what was selected and query the database based on that selection. But how do I find what was selected? I don't want the user to have to click a submit button, I just want to figure out what they selected.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <label for="medProcDataList" class="form-label">Medical Procedures with hospital codes</label>
    <input class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" id="medProcDataList" placeholder="Type to search...">
    <datalist id="datalistOptions">
      <!-- this is populated with 70 options that look like this
      <option value='216: Cardiac valve'>-->
    </datalist>
</form>
```

jquery:

```
var strMedProcedures = "";
var procCode, procDescription;
$.ajax({
        url: "php/getMedProcedures.php", //see this php page to see the db query
            //data: {},
            method: "POST",
            success: function(output) {
                 objMedProcedures = JSON.parse(output);
                
                 if (objMedProcedures.length > 0) {
                    for (var i=0; i< objMedProcedures.length; i++) {
                        procCode = objMedProcedures[i].procedure_codes;
                        procDescription = objMedProcedures[i].procedure_name;
                        strMedProcedures += "<option value='" + procCode + ": " + procDescription + "'>\n"; //build string of options
                    }
                    $('#datalistOptions').html(strMedProcedures); //populate datalist with the options
                 } 
                 return false;
                 
            },
            error: function(jxhr, statusText, err) {
                // Error, handle it
                console.log(statusText + " " + err);
            }
        });

$('#medProcDataList').change(function() {
    var $option = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    console.log($option); //returns 'undefined'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to get the value directly from `#medProcDataList`. You don't have to worry about finding the `<option>`

```js
$('#medProcDataList').change(function() {

  var $selectedValue = $(this).val();

  console.log($selectedValue); //returns "216: Cardiac valve"
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form method="post" action="">
  <label for="medProcDataList" class="form-label">Medical Procedures with hospital codes</label>
  <input class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" id="medProcDataList" placeholder="Type to search...">
  <datalist id="datalistOptions">
    <!-- this is populated with 70 options that look like this
      <option value='216: Cardiac valve'>-->
      <option value='216: Cardiac valve'>
  </datalist>
</form>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```